# Docker build with buildkit and mirror.gcr.io fails on uncached images

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit

When building a Dockerfile which refers to an image which is not cached on `mirror.gcr.io`, and when enabled with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`; the build fails:

```
$ cat Dockerfile.test
FROM debian:10

$ sudo cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
        "registry-mirrors": ["https://mirror.gcr.io"]
}

$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -f Dockerfile.test . 
[+] Building 1.0s (4/4) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.test                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 42B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:10                                                                                                                                         0.6s
 => ERROR [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/debian:10                                                                                                                                                           0.3s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/debian:10                                                                                                                                                                 0.3s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:10:
------
------
 > [1/1] FROM docker.io/library/debian:10:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to load cache key: docker.io/library/debian:10 not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest (stable) docker does not have an up to date buildkit. Buildkit 0.7 does actually failover to the normal docker Hub if an image is not found on a mirror.

As [per instruction](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1787#issuecomment-724936347) of @tonistiigi on Github: Use docker 20.10 (currently beta), or use `docker buildx` with the newer buildkit.